# Univariate vs Multivariate Gaussian Distribution in MLE Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression, gaussian

I had a doubt while doing Andrew Ng's CS 229.

For reference: https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes1.pdf

In linear regression, while using MLE to calculate parameters, we assume that y has a univariate Gaussian distribution p(⃗y|X; θ). This makes sense to me when probability of the data is viewed as a function of y, for a fixed value of theta.

Then in the notes it says: "When we wish to explicitly view this as a function of θ, we will instead call it the likelihood function [given by]: L(θ) = L(θ; X, ⃗y) = p(⃗y|X; θ)"
Here's my doubt - Since our probability density function ( (which we are calling likelihood function) is now a function of θ, does that mean we are saying θ has a Gaussian distribution?

If that is the case, since θ is multivariable, we are essentially giving our probability density function a multivariable input. Then shouldn't our probability distribution be a multivariate gaussian distribution now?  I don't understand how changing a single variable input to a multivariable input is changing nothing about our function?

Comment: As mentioned in page 12 of the notes $\theta$ is NOT a random variable. Hence, it doesn't have a Gaussian distribution. Writing $L(\theta)$ is only convenient to empathize that data $x^{(i)},y^{(i)}$ is already given and we are left to find $\theta$. $\theta$ are just parameters in the distribution which we want to optimize.

Comment: Got it, thanks!